# How to give argument to write registry?

Tags: c++, arguments, registry

I wrote the code below to edit a registry value:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  HKEY hkey = NULL;

  const char* evtwvr = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Event Viewer";
  const char* exepath = "file://C:\\Users\\MrUser\\Desktop\\temp.exe;

  LONG rgdt = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, (LPCSTR)evtwvr, 0 , KEY_WRITE, &hkey);
  if (rgdt == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    RegSetValueEx(hkey, (LPCSTR)"MicrosoftRedirectionUrl", 0, REG_SZ, (unsigned char*)exepath, strlen(exepath));
    RegCloseKey(hkey);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It simple edits the registry key and writes the exe path as a value.

But I want to do it like this:

`myprogram.exe C:\Users\User\MrUser\temp.exe`

and pass the input parameter into the registry value.

Comment: [what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024202/11128312)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace `exepath` with `argv[1]` instead.

Also, your `LPCSTR` casts are unnecessary. And you need to add `+1` to `strlen()` because `REG_SZ` requires the string's null terminator to be written.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  if (argc < 2) return 1;

  const char* evtwvr = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Event Viewer";

  HKEY hkey = NULL;
  LONG rgdt = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, evtwvr, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &hkey);
  if (rgdt == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    RegSetValueExA(hkey, "MicrosoftRedirectionUrl", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)argv[1], strlen(argv[1])+1);
    RegCloseKey(hkey);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

That being said, since you want to use a command line parameter to edit the Registry, you could just use Windows built-in [`reg` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg) instead, eg:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Event Viewer" /v MicrosoftRedirectionUrl /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\User\MrUser\temp.exe" /f
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed response. It worked very well